# Server gets hanged after sometimes

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, server, apache2.4

I run a PHP app with Apache2.4 and MySQL on the same server. When the system restarts, it works fine for some time, it handles all the requests/responses easily without any problem. But suddenly it gets stuck somewhere.
Here are some log details

> htop

[image: htop command result]
It seems MySQL using memory more than expected, but when I run mysqltuner command, it looks fine.

`./mysqltuner.pl`

```
>>  MySQLTuner 2.0.9
 * Jean-Marie Renouard <jmrenouard@gmail.com>
 * Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
>>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: root
Please enter your MySQL administrative password: [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] log_error is set to stderr, but this script can't read stderr
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 13.1M (Tables: 65)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 20.4K (Tables: 6)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Views Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Triggers Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Routines Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to unsupported feature for MySQL 8
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1h 33m 1s (2K q [0.467 qps], 55 conn, TX: 16M, RX: 642K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 90% / 10%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 964.1M
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 415.7M
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 88.0M global + 9.9M per thread (10 max threads)
[--] Performance_schema Max memory usage: 228M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 336.7M (34.92% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 415.7M (43.11% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 20% (2/10)
[!!] Aborted connections: 9.09% (5/55)
[!!] Name resolution is active: a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection which can reduce performance
[--] Query cache has been removed since MySQL 8.0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 374 sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 161 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 96% (2 created / 55 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 93% (9K hits / 9K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (398)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (10 immediate / 10 locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% (191 Memory / 191 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by Performance_schema: 228.9M
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] MyISAM Metrics are disabled since MySQL 8.0.
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 64.0M / 13.1M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 8.0M * 2/64.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.11% (144492 hits / 145796 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 69.68% (1721 hits / 2470 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 749 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours: recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
Variables to adjust:
    skip-name-resolve=1
```

`strace` log for apache

> ps auxw | grep apache | awk '{print" -p " $2}' | xargs sudo strace

Full output:

```
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=52 /* 0.52 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718263258
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=52 /* 0.52 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718264142
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=52 /* 0.52 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718265958
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718266637
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718268179
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718269300
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718271166
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1491] epoll_wait(18,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid  1491] <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2403259792, u64=139966797501840}}], 2, 10000) = 1
[pid   955] times( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] accept4(6,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... times resumed>{tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718273373
[pid  1491] <... accept4 resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(47296), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:122.164.182.5", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] futex(0x7f4c8f893000, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1491] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid   955] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] getsockname(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... wait4 resumed>0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid  1491] <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:10.0.0.27", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28]) = 0
[pid  1487] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718276832
[pid  1491] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] epoll_wait(18,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... getrandom resumed>"\xf4\x2b\x54\x44\x40\x25\x47\x3e\xc7\x84\x14\xac\x75\xc2\x92\x4b\x28\x96\x0e\x35\xee\xe7\x92\xfc\x25\x10\x20\xc1\x46\xb8\xce\x01", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1487] <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2403259792, u64=139966797501840}}, {events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2403259824, u64=139966797501872}}], 2, 10000) = 2
[pid  1491] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] accept4(4,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... getrandom resumed>"\x28\x05\x2c\xb6\x2c\xf2\x4e\x39\x74\x7c\xe5\x2b\x32\xcd\x36\x44\x72\xab\x7d\xdc\x92\x96\xf4\x7f\x8a\x3f\x33\x27\x5a\x59\xd4\xcf", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1487] <... accept4 resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(21738), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:192.155.90.118", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid  1491] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] futex(0x7f4c8f893000, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... openat resumed>)       = 20
[pid  1487] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1763] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1763] epoll_wait(18, [{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2403259792, u64=139966797501840}}], 2, 10000) = 1
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1487] getsockname(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] accept4(6,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] read(20,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(80), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:10.0.0.27", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28]) = 0
[pid  1763] <... accept4 resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(60522), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:122.164.182.5", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid  1763] futex(0x7f4c8f893000, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... read resumed>"\244>5\273\2\331Kz\371\357\232\317fwL'\204\206\213\260\260\3226ui\300\205\332\r\346\237\216"..., 512) = 512
[pid  1491] getrandom("\x7c\x45\xf9\xbe\x87\xdf\x4f\xc0\x05\x0e\x85\xc6\xa2\x71\x80\x09\x8b\x4e\x2f\xc5\x78\x5e\x5f\xf3\x60\x39\x4f\x6a\x54\x6b\x94\x0b", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1491] close(20)                   = 0
[pid  1763] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1490] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1490] epoll_wait(18,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getsockname(19, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:10.0.0.27", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28]) = 0
[pid   955] <... clone resumed>, child_tidptr=0x7f4c8f4d2a50) = 2425
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=53 /* 0.53 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718278772
[pid  1763] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] fcntl(19, F_GETFL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] fcntl(19, F_GETFL <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid  1763] <... getrandom resumed>"\x86\x01\x3b\xdb\x7d\x70\xcd\xe9\xf4\x43\xdd\x8d\x14\x0a\x00\xfc\x1b\xc8\xad\xf0\xa1\x27\x8e\x47\x42\x8f\xd8\x47\xf1\x88\x04\xa0", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1487] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid  1491] fcntl(19, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] fcntl(19, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] <... epoll_wait resumed>[], 2, 10000) = 0
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1491] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1487] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1763] <... getrandom resumed>"\x81\x05\xbd\xf6\x18\x2c\xbd\x7a\x3d\xda\x1c\x25\x6b\x3c\x02\xdc\xe2\xbd\xf1\x4f\xc8\x85\x28\xce\xf6\x8c\x81\xff\x8a\x5c\x39\x1c", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1763] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] epoll_wait(18,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... openat resumed>)       = 20
[pid  1490] <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2403259792, u64=139966797501840}}], 2, 10000) = 1
[pid   955] <... clone resumed>, child_tidptr=0x7f4c8f4d2a50) = 2426
[pid   955] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4c8f4d2a50) = 2427
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=54 /* 0.54 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718280136
[pid  1763] read(20,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] accept4(6,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] read(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... read resumed>"f\246\312\v\264\234\301\204O6\251Z\314\26\367\341#\rG\31'>g_3!A2\310\271TZ"..., 512) = 512
[pid  1491] read(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] <... accept4 resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(37126), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:192.0.102.40", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... read resumed>"\26\3\1\2\0\1\0\1\374\3\3\16\266\201\25\237\330\4\205h\f\366\27\244\210)R\2438\350p\2"..., 8000) = 517
[pid  1490] futex(0x7f4c8f893000, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] <... read resumed>"\26\3\1\0\205\1\0\0\201\3\3\0\206\204\337\362N\241\343\265\30Rj\366\r\221O\343]_\330\277"..., 8000) = 138
[pid  1763] <... getrandom resumed>"\xa3\xc1\xb1\xc3\x87\xbc\xd2\x75\xbb\xe3\x75\x0a\xd2\x7d\x48\x51\x08\xb4\x56\x43\xb3\x25\xa3\x18\xaf\x71\xb4\xd5\xa2\xc3\xaa\x8b", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1490] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1763] close(20 <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] getsockname(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... close resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1490] <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:10.0.0.27", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [128 => 28]) = 0
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=54 /* 0.54 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718285330
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... clone resumed>, child_tidptr=0x7f4c8f4d2a50) = 2429
[pid  1490] <... getrandom resumed>"\x2d\x84\x03\x1f\xc6\xd2\x1b\x4e\x0e\x12\x30\xd1\x30\xf7\xff\xa8\x72\x8a\x07\x46\x36\xd4\xce\x62\xfe\x58\x45\x36\xd1\xa7\xf8\x6b", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1490] getrandom("\xd2\xc0\x7f\x2a\x6c\xf7\x41\x47\x99\xe6\xde\x25\x35\x2c\x0c\xaf\xf6\x40\x49\x5d\x31\xc5\xdb\xda\xe3\x95\x9c\x5e\x8d\x1a\x6a\xc1", 32, 0) = 32
[pid   955] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] fcntl(19, F_GETFL <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... wait4 resumed>0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid  1490] <... openat resumed>)       = 20
[pid  1763] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid   955] times( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] fcntl(19, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] read(20,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0
[pid   955] <... times resumed>{tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=54 /* 0.54 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718287566
[pid  1490] <... read resumed>"\251FO\252\273v\177Fy|\36w\363+[W\224;v\314\303-\246\3111-\275/\377\21\5\366"..., 512) = 512
[pid  1491] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] read(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1491
[pid  1490] getrandom( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... read resumed>"\26\3\1\2\0\1\0\1\374\3\3\275\4\232\26s\344E\340\226\241\36\214&\242S\325\2623\257\363Z"..., 8000) = 517
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1491] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] <... getrandom resumed>"\x68\xf1\xe1\xcb\x01\x79\x0b\x9e\x1b\xf5\x81\x57\xb5\x89\xcd\x3e\x9c\x2d\xa0\x90\x3f\x1d\xf8\xc8\xc0\x2c\xee\x5e\xa5\x5b\x5e\x81", 32, 0) = 32
[pid  1491] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1491
[pid  1490] close(20)                   = 0
[pid   955] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4c8f4d2a50) = 2430
[pid   955] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... clone resumed>, child_tidptr=0x7f4c8f4d2a50) = 2431
[pid  1491] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1491
[pid  1491] getpid()                    = 1491
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=55 /* 0.55 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718294976
[pid  1490] fcntl(19, F_GETFL)          = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid  1490] fcntl(19, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] <... fcntl resumed>)        = 0
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=55 /* 0.55 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718297256
[pid  1487] writev(19, [{iov_base="HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nDate: "..., iov_len=182}, {iov_base="<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//"..., iov_len=301}], 2 <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] <... writev resumed>)       = 483
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... times resumed>{tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=55 /* 0.55 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718299906
[pid  1763] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1763
[pid  1491] writev(19, [{iov_base="\26\3\3\0z\2\0\0v\3\3z\3328q\270\257C\216\215\274\r\272\207T\252m\366\276>\231\225"..., iov_len=4096}], 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] read(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] write(16, "192.155.90.118 - - [15/Nov/2022:"..., 79 <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] <... read resumed>"\26\3\1\1;\1\0\0017\3\3\vtK+\335>\354=\317,\0\311{?{\354\31F\17d!"..., 8000) = 320
[pid  1491] <... writev resumed>)       = 4096
[pid  1763] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1763
[pid  1487] <... write resumed>)        = 79
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1491] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getpid()                    = 1763
[pid  1763] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1491
[pid  1763] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1763
[pid  1487] times( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] writev(19, [{iov_base="\26\3\3\0z\2\0\0v\3\3\330\352\265\276\271\264\2\333S\33\2\226\20\230M\0\23\241\201&\354"..., iov_len=4096}], 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... writev resumed>)       = 4096
[pid  1491] writev(19, [{iov_base="\271\345\340\200a\352\231Q\323\201\274\2212\342F\350\322\315\22<\364\v'\336\272\257\2004\303\275\n\274"..., iov_len=486}], 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] <... times resumed>{tms_utime=329 /* 3.29 s */, tms_stime=240 /* 2.40 s */, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1718309667
[pid   955] <... wait4 resumed>0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid  1491] <... writev resumed>)       = 486
[pid  1490] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1490
[pid  1490] getpid()                    = 1490
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=55 /* 0.55 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718313368
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1491] read(19,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] shutdown(19, SHUT_WR <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1763
[pid  1491] <... read resumed>"", 8000) = 0
[pid  1490] <... getpid resumed>)       = 1490
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1487] <... shutdown resumed>)     = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid  1490] getpid()                    = 1490
[pid  1487] close(19)                   = 0
[pid   955] wait4(-1, 0x7ffd964d6c24, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
[pid   955] times({tms_utime=19 /* 0.19 s */, tms_stime=55 /* 0.55 s */, tms_cutime=1686 /* 16.86 s */, tms_cstime=389 /* 3.89 s */}) = 1718320078
[pid  1763] writev(19, [{iov_base="\230\363\3727\306\304X\\\240\260\236\366}A;Q\366\325\247\347\t&<\255s\361,\351~Q@\237"..., iov_len=486}], 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] read(7,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1763] <... writev resumed>)       = 486
[pid  1487] <... read resumed>0x7ffd964d6b1f, 1) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid   955] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] writev(19, [{iov_base="\26\3\3\0z\2\0\0v\3\3\242\215\257\"\330\375N\211\204\371P4/\5[\7n\312l\330\376"..., iov_len=4096}], 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  1487] futex(0x7f4c8f893000, FUTEX_LOCK_PI, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  1490] <... writev resumed>)       = 4096
[pid  1487] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid  1487] epoll_wait(18,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   955] <... pselect6 resumed>)     = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  1487] <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=2403259792, u64=139966797501840}}], 2, 10000) = 1
```

MySql stat when it got hanged

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db         | Command | Time | State                  | Info                  |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|  5 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL       | Daemon  |  998 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                  |
|  8 | root            | localhost | NULL       | Query   |  103 | init                   | show full processlist |
| 49 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Sleep   |  209 |                        | NULL                  |
| 50 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Sleep   |  209 |                        | NULL                  |
| 51 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Query   |   61 | starting               | NULL                  |
| 52 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Sleep   |  209 |                        | NULL                  |
| 53 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Query   |   64 | starting               | NULL                  |
| 54 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Sleep   |  209 |                        | NULL                  |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (2 min 53.49 sec)

mysql> show full processlist;
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db         | Command | Time | State                  | Info                  |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|  5 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL       | Daemon  | 1900 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                  |
|  8 | root            | localhost | NULL       | Query   |  135 | init                   | show full processlist |
| 49 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Sleep   |  494 |                        | NULL                  |
| 50 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Query   |    0 | starting               | NULL                  |
| 51 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Sleep   |  427 | NULL                   | NULL                  |
| 52 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Query   |    0 | starting               | NULL                  |
| 53 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Query   |   83 | starting               | NULL                  |
| 54 | root            | localhost | ahmadasjad | Query   |    0 | starting               | NULL                  |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (2 min 52.07 sec)
```

When it was not hanged, I was getting results in mili-seconds

Config: ***ubuntu 22.04***, ***PHP 7.4***, ***Apache2.4***, ***MySQL 5.6***

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What's in the MySQL log?

Comment: All log files `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, `/var/log/mysql/error.log.*.gz` have an empty value

Comment: Can this be easily reproduced? does it happen even with no traffic or happens on a specific request coming from your php app? can you `show full processlist;` to what query might have caused high memory usage? a few more check list in this link:
https://severalnines.com/blog/what-check-if-mysql-memory-utilisation-high/

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. Yes, it happens even with no traffic at all

Comment: @runwuf added the log for `show full processlist;`

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
F) complete www.MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report or similar. 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide 8.0 ram conserving suggestions.

Comment: Adding swap space equal to RAM helped me from preventing it from getting hung. But still, I'm not able to find out why it's consuming so much memory even when there is too little or no request.
Comments from @WilsonHauck, @ runwuf, @ Rick James helped to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I think that `htop` says that there is no "swap" allocated.  Meanwhile, RAM is nearly full.

I recommend lowering `max_connections` to 10 in `my.cnf` (and restart `mysqld`.  This may help some.  If not adequate, then I suggest any of these:

- Add some swap space, or
- See what can be shrunk, or
- Add more RAM.

Normally, I would recommend lowering `innodb_buffer_pool_size` as a quick fix for out-of-ram-and-no-swap, but it is already dangerously low at only 64M.

Comment: I disagree with 3rd option(Add more RAM). Earlier it was running with 500 MB RAM on DO server. But there the MySQL version was 5.7, and here I have 8. There is not too much hit on the web, generally, it's me. Not even 1 request/second

Comment: Well it looks like you are nearly out of RAM and have no swap space.

Comment: The hardware (or virtual resource allocation) this is running on looks inadequate. It needs more RAM and more swap space. MySQL server (like most DB Servers) are very RAM hungry. Give it some more RAM and swap space and it will likely be OK. Especially if you can't find any tuning issues with the DB. It's not that memory requirements are growing exponentially over time or anything like that.

Comment: I quick win: add at least 1 Gb of swap and configure kernel `swappiness` to a low value such as 10. More details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916)